# Selenium to scroll down a div

Tags: python, selenium

How can I scroll down and up inside a div using Selenium? I looked everywhere on the internet. Only solutions for pages.

```python
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/nav/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/span')
    
element.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element )
```

Comment: Did you try `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element )` instead of `element.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element )`?

Comment: Also Jason's comment looks good. He dropped the comment in as i was typing the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The actions class is capable of scrolling.

This import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

This function:

```
def ScrollIntoView(element):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Assuming your element exists and is ready on the page you can Call it as such:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/nav/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/span')
ScrollIntoView(element)
```